# Recovering a healthy RAID disk from an Ubuntu server: mdadm no recogniseable superblock

Tags: raid, mdadm

I've had a series of different issues with recovering a RAID disk, ending with the error reported in the subject. Please **skip** the long story to come to the conclusions if you want.

**Long story:**

- I set up an ubuntu server machine a couple of years ago with two 1TB disks in RAID1.
- recently the machine was faulty and I dismantled it, taking the two HDD.
- I managed to connect one of the disks to my laptop via USB and browse it correctly through mdadm.
- Bought a Synology NAS and placed the other disk inside it, to create a new RAID system. Of course this way it was formatted and I had only one good disk with my old data.
- Connected the good disk to the NAS via USB with the intent to copy all the old data to the freshly formatted disk inside the NAS. I managed to create a mdadm array in the NAS thanks to this guide http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_manually_mount_a_USB_Hard_Disk,_including_a_disk_that_was_part_of_a_RAID1_array and managed to see that the disk had memory of its previous RAID configuration (in my laptop):
  mdadm --examine --scan /dev/sdk3 
  returned the line of information I expected
- However the NAS at the end could not mount the disk (/dev/sdq1) to the filesystem (say /mnt/usb), with a generic "No such device" error. Apparently it seems mount in busybox (on which the NAS is based) is reluctant on giving further suggestions (http://www.silas.net.br/tech/linux/busybox-troubleshooting.html)
- Then I thought "well, if I can't copy data via USB in the NAS I will connect the disk to my laptop and transfer trough ethernet". Good idea. Unfortunately, in the process of creating the array the NAS probably destroyed the original superblocks, so when I connected it to the laptop (Linux Mint ubuntu version) the partition showed up inside the file manager (mdadm worked fine and mapped the partition in /dev/mapper) but could not be mounted: raid mount: /dev/md1: can't read superblock
- trying to fix with e2fsck didn't help
- trying to fix with e2fsck -b  didn't help
- All the information were ok, like those in mdadm --examine --scan /dev/sdk3

**Conclusions:**

- I rebooted the laptop. Now the raid is not even assembled automatically by mdadm... I think the disk lost its UUID? Can it be? I see dmesg correctly connects the disk:

sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

and a partition sdb1, but I cannot find the disk in /dev/disk/by-uuid

The RAID info is lost: mdadm --examine --scan /dev/sdk3 returns no information

- Trying to manually create a new md returns:
  $ mdadm -A --verbose --run /dev/md3 /dev/sdb1 
  mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md3
  mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
  mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has no superblock - assembly aborted

I tried to restore a number of backup superblocks with:

e2fsck -b  /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768

I got the superblock backup address with mke2fs -n /dev/sdb1

**Is the disk totally fried??? Is it normally so that utilities overwrite important info on a disk and make it unusable?**

---

**Additional info**:

$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT

parted /dev/sdb

Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: SAMSUNG HD103SI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      17,4kB  1000GB  1000GB                     raid

Answer (score 0):

With testdisk I realized that Linux RAID and Linux LVM2 partitioning were coexisting, so with testdisk I wrote the LVM partition table and I was able to mount the two ext3 partitions inside the disk.